# YouTube API Error 403 When IS Enabled in Google Dashboard

Tags: youtube-api

Using Javascript + jquery Fetch I was able to search using the YouTube API - then it stopped working and now I get error 403 telling me

> Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 482017898664 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=482017898664 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry

However when I go to that address my API IS ENABLED.  And I can run a search from https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/.

Why has this stopped working and how do I get it to work again since its saying my API IS ENABLED.

NOTE - "wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry" - I've waited 3 days and its still not working.

Comment: Can you show your fetch request? (don't show API key). When I tried to fetch from Youtube API using my key, I can't do it in Javascript, something with CORS not allowing access.

Comment: Example - with bad API key at https://repl.it/@TamiWilliams/youtube-example-DOM

Comment: Was able to fix by going into Google API Dashboard - disabling the API, deleting the credentials, creating a NEW project, enabling the API on that new project & then creating new credentials - this new api key works.

Comment: Good to know! Congrats for figuring that out

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is because youtube disabled your project's access to Youtube data.

Two things you can check if that's really what happened to you.

1. You should receive an email from Youtube with subject 
   [FYI] Youtube disabled your inactive project's data API service
2. Your Queries per day in the quota page was set to 0. (and you are not allowed to edit it)

The only way to get your access back for the same project is to fill up this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform) and wait for their action.